# problem when starting firstSpring boot App on intellig IDEA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-22 04:22:47.552 ERROR 2548 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: attach pom.xml or gradle.build code

Comment: This error happens when you're using Spring Data JPA (`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`) without a proper database configuration (hence it can't find `spring.datasource.url`) and without an embedded datasource from which it could automatically derive the configuration. Without your code, and an idea to which database you're trying to connect (if any), we cannot help you any further, and that's why I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Feel free to add the necessary information to the question and ping me (start your comment with `@g00glen00b`) when done.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you didn't put your main class in a specific package.
create a package and put all your classes in it.
spring `@ComponentScan` which come along with `@SpringBootApplication` use packages to scan your classes.